# Prevent PuTTY's "Are you sure you want to close this session" popup?

Tags: putty

I like Putty, a lot. However, I open and close a huge number of Putty windows each day and every time I close a window I get a popup box with

> Are you sure you want to close this session?

It's incredibly annoying. Yes, Putty, I would like to close the session. *That's why I clicked the freaking close button!*

Is there any way to prevent this popup in Putty?

EDIT: I'm running Windows 7 x64 and Putty 0.63.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use this option on the `Window -> Behaviour` page

[image]

and don't forget to save this as *Default Settings* on the `Session` page to make it permanent.

Comment: I can't believe it. I looked all through the settings and somehow missed this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you have to do it for every single (pre-existing) session!!! (Contrary to what @mpy just said.)  For each session, you must:  1) click ONCE on the session, 2) click "Load" 3) Click Window->Behavior to uncheck "Warn before closing window" 4) click Session, 5) click Save

Comment: @JamesBowery: It seems we use different wording: I meant with session a new connection to an arbitrary host (_default_ profile is used). Otherwise you are right, every (already saved) profile you have to edit once.

Answer (score 4):

As @mpy correctly answered, go to *Window > Behavior > Warn before closing window*.

---

Alternatively, particularly if you are keyboard-centric, use <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> keyboard shortcut. On *nix systems, it's an equivalent of `logout` command and will take your PuTTY window with it (if *Close window on exit* is set to its default value of *Only on clean exit*).

Comment: Good to know! Though, this might not work on other connections than SSH, e.g. COM, depending on the target you are connected with :)